# How Can I Add Dictionaries to a Vector?

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator, transform

I am trying to populate a dictionary of the form `map<string, vector<map<string,string>> >` groceryDict but I am running into an issue where I cannot get the key and value strings out of the dictionary. In `map<string, vector<map<string,string>> >` groceryDict the first key is represents the type of grocery item ie: fruit, vegetable, or meat. That keys value is a vector of dictionaries. Each dictionary item of the vector has an item name and quantity ie: Tomatoes:2 or Strawberries:5.

1. I have tried the following code:

```
    vector<map<string, string>>rowVect;
    map<string,string> rowDict={{'Bananas','2'}{'Apples','5'}};
    for (map<string, string>::iterator it = rowDict.begin(); it != 
    rowDict.end();it++) {
     string x = it->first;
     string y = it->second;
     rowVect.push_back({x,y});
     }
```

2. I have also tried the following code:

```
    vector<pair<string, string>>rowVect;
    map<string,string> rowDict={{'Bananas','2'}{'Apples','5'}};
    std::transform(rowDict.begin(), rowDict.end(), back_inserter(rowVect), 
    [&](std::pair<string,string> &p) {rowVect.push_back( p ); });
```

I expected the code to compile but instead I received the following errors:
1. Error C2675 unary '++': '_Iter' does not define this operator or a 
    conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
2. Error C2664::operator ()(std::pair &) const': 
    cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::pair' to 
    'std::pair &'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using the incorrect data type. Use of

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>>> groceryDict;
```

or

```
std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, int>> groceryDict;
```

will work better.

The following block of code should work.

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>> rowVect;

std::map<std::string, int> rowDict = {{"Bananas", 2}, {"Apples", 5}};
for ( auto& item: rowDict )
{
   std::string x = item.first;
   int y = item.second;
   rowVect.push_back({x, y});
}
```

or the simpler version of the `for` loop.

```
for ( auto& item: rowDict )
{
   rowVect.push_back(item);
}
```

Comment: I think it was using pair instead of map within the vector. Thanks for the help!